# How can Newton's Divided Difference Interpolation accuracy be improved?

Tags: interpolation, interpolation-theory

Are there any modifications to Newton's divided difference interpolation that can be made in order to improve the accuracy of the value given, specifically for exponential functions such as $y=e^{-x}-x$?

Comment: Why do you **need** interpolation to compute $e^{-x}-x$?

Comment: To find an estimation of its root without using original algebra methods.

Comment: To find the **roots** of $e^{-x}-x$ you need to compute the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).